# How to subscribe to a Durable TOPIC using Apache camel / Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Whenever i start my subscriber, it is not appearing on my activeMQ under "Active Durable Topic Subscribers" section. Which means it is not a durable topic subscriber yet. How can i make it durable subscriber?

```
JmsComponent jmsComponent = JmsComponent
        .jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory, jmsTransactionManager);
// TODO
jmsComponent.setClientId(subscriptionClientId);
jmsComponent.setDurableSubscriptionName(subscriptionName);
jmsComponent.setSubscriptionDurable(true); // This is enabled by default
//jmsComponent.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConcurrentConsumers);
jmsComponent.setAcknowledgementMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

return jmsComponent;
```

P.S: It works fine for Non-durable subscribers. I added the below code in an attempt to make it durable. Am i missing something ? Do i need to add anything else?

```
jmsComponent.setClientId(subscriptionClientId);
jmsComponent.setDurableSubscriptionName(subscriptionName);
jmsComponent.setSubscriptionDurable(true); // This is enabled by default
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you using JMS component instead of ActiveMQ component?

Comment: Hi reason for using generic JMS component instead of activeMQ is to support different clients like some of them will have IBM-MQ and some of them will have activeMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by passing the subscription details as query string param as below;

myapp.jms.topic.inbound1=jms:topic:myFirstTopic?clientId=ABC&durableSubscriptionName=ABC

myapp.jms.topic.inbound2=jms:topic:mysecondTopic?clientId=XYZ&durableSubscriptionName=XYZ

Comment: Shouldn't the [clientId](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) be unique per JMS Connection? Does it mean we should setClientId on our jmsComponent once only and just use different unique durableSubscriptionName in our camel uri passed as query string param?